# how can i get Max value of a column in GreenDAO using QueryBuilder?

Tags: android, greendao

I'm still rusty when it comes to ORM's, but i really love GREENDAO, for its extreme simplicity and speed.
Can i please know how to get the Max value of a column in my table in GreenDao.
Say i have a table with id and post id, and i want to get the highest value of post id?
I've tried using the raw sql builder, but no way

```
public void getMaxId(int postId)
   {
       return postsDao.queryBuilder().where(new WhereCondition.StringCondition(SELECT MAX(PostId) FROM POSTS).build());
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it will get the job done.

```
public Long getMaxId() {
    List<Posts> maxPostIdRow = _postsDao.queryBuilder().where(PostsDao.Properties.Postid.isNotNull()).orderDesc(PostsDao.Properties.Postid).limit(1).list();
    Long maxPostId = maxPostIdRow.get(0).getPostid();
    return maxPostId;
}
```

The strategy here is to sort the database table by the field you want, grab only the top row, and then return the value of the field you sorted by.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
  Query query = collectionDao.queryBuilder().where(
            new WhereCondition.StringCondition("UPDATE_TIME=(SELECT MAX(PostId) FROM POSTS)")).build();
```